# Setting current year value as integer

Tags: java

I would like to get the current year ans set the value as:

```
"1" if year is 2015
"2" if year is 2016
```

and so on. Is it possible?

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Using this method gives me year as 2015 however, I want to equate it to 1 or 2 and so on based on date.

Comment: Are you asking about subtracting `2014` to the `year` variable?

Comment: try:
`int year = 2015 or 2016 or anything;`
`year = 0 - ( Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - year) + 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you want to handle anything before 2015, but here you go:

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 2014;
```

Comment: That would actually do it. The application does not display past dates. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SriramIlango no problem. upvote and accept if it helped?

Answer (score 1):

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) % 2014;
```

also works